# pushing and retriving data

Tags: iphone, xml, ios, ipad

**I want to fetch the data from a xml file and then push into sqlite database .
So can someone suggest the best one from NSMutableArray an nsdictionary to use to store data so that it will be easy to retrieve and store it back to sqlite database**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest just using [Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/cdprogrammingguide.html), that way you will always be working with simple and easy to use Objects.

Comment: which is the better option to use NSMutableArray or NSDictionary or we will use one one of this or mixed. but the best way pleasae:!

Comment: @shudhanshupradhan If you are going that route then I would say NSDictionary since they are key-value pairs.